# Как с помощью CSS реализовать такую конструкцию блоков

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

http://prntscr.com/jv0qwf

На скрине отмечено, как сейчас отображаются блоки, и как нужно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: здесь, здание, здоровье (с) Ирина Петровна

Comment: видел что можно сделать как то с помощью matrix3d, но не понял как

Comment: @Freezkill скриншоты на сторонних ресурсах быстро умирают, поэтому их лучше постить здесь CTRL+G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transform: skew(N)` + `overflow: hidden`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
}

.skew-block {
  width: 55vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
}

.skew-block:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

.offset {
  margin-left: -8rem;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="offset">
    <div class="skew-block"></div>
    <div class="skew-block"></div>
    <div class="skew-block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: в целом не плохо, но есть одно "но" - в середине блоков <div class="skew-block"></div> будут картинки, и естественно большая часть их будет обрезана, нужно как то сделать так что бы блок <div class="skew-block"></div> не вылазил за родителя.

Comment: @Freezkill, а в чём проблема дать этим блокам `background`, который вскоре просто позиционировать как нужно?